# Inserting Iterator values in Microsoft Access database

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

Here I am reading excel file and trying to insert values into database.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {

    Myconnection con = new Myconnection();
    Statement stmt = null;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/upload.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator ite = sheet.rowIterator();

    PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into ParcelCoordinates(Subdivision,ParcelNo,PointID,Easting,Northing,Height) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");      
    while(ite.hasNext()){
        Row row = (Row) ite.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cite = row.cellIterator();       

        while(cite.hasNext()){
             Cell p = cite.next();
            prepStmt.setString(1, p.getStringCellValue());            
            prepStmt.setString(2,p.getStringCellValue());
            prepStmt.setString(3,p.getStringCellValue());
            prepStmt.setString(4,p.getStringCellValue());
            prepStmt.setString(5,p.getStringCellValue());
            prepStmt.setString(6,p.getStringCellValue());
            prepStmt.addBatch();                      

          }      

        System.out.println(cite);           
        while(cite.hasNext()){
            Cell c = cite.next();
            System.out.print(c.toString() +"  ");       //Gives single cell values  correctly   

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    fis.close();
}
```

What is wrong here. Getting error message:

```
Exception   :java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file '(unknown)'.Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.concretepage.poi.upload.main(upload.java:30)
```

Connection file:

```
public class Myconnection
{
    public Myconnection(){}
    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        Connection con = null;          
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
          //  String accessFileName = "C:/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/CUInfo";         
            String accessFileName = "C:/CUID/RequestForCUIDInfo";
            String connURL="jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+accessFileName+".accdb;";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL, "","");
            System.out.println("connection created successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception   :" + e);
        }
        return con;
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Myconnection cf = new Myconnection();
       cf.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: The excel file seems to be found, but it looks like your program can't find (or open) the MS Access database file. Can you try to just add a main-method in the MyConnection class (new MyConnection()) just trying to open the database file?

Comment: @claj: thanks, I did not understand what you want to say. Can you please show code

Comment: What happens when you run the class MyConnection? Do you get the same error there?

Comment: @claj: yeah, there was mistake in file name. I update `String connURL="jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+accessFileName+".mdb;";`

Comment: @claj: no still there is issue. It does not insert into database, neither it prints the values as in code